# search() using for loop.

Tags: javascript, loops

This is a part of codeacademy project. The part from the beginning to list(); function is more or less working. My task is to make a search function using for loop. 
Thank you in advance.

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",

    phoneNumber: "(650) 777 - 7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",

    phoneNumber: "(650) 888 - 8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson (person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

var list =  function(){
    var contactsNumber = contacts.length;
    for(i=0; i<=contactsNumber; i++){
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
};

list();

var search = function(lastName){
    var number = contacts.length;
    for(i=0; i<= number; i++){
        if(lastName === contacts[i].lastName){
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
};

search("Jones");
```

Comment: And what's your problem? What don't you understand?

Comment: In addition to what @DavidThomas said, the least you could do is provide (by editing into your question) any errors you're encountering, and a link to the Codacademy exercise

Answer (score 2):

When you have 2 items in the array, you want the indices `0` and `1` to loop for, and *not* `2`. So, use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < number; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

That exercise is bugged (or was don't know if they fixed it) You have to run all the other functions to get it correct:

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",

    phoneNumber: "(650) 777 - 7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",

    phoneNumber: "(650) 888 - 8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson (person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

var list = function ()
{
    var contactsNum = contacts.length;
    for (i=0; i < contactsNum; i++)
    printPerson(contacts[i]);
};

function search(lastName){
     var items = contacts.length;
     for(i = 0; i < items; i++){
         if(contacts[i].lastName == lastName)
              printPerson(contacts[i]);      
     }
}
list();
search("Jones");
```

Comment: It doesn't? I get success message even if I copy/paste it :(

Answer (score 0):

Because you used the `var` keywords you don't have access to contacts in the function. Remove the `var` keyword before contacts and it should work fine.

Comment: The part from the beginning to the list(); does the job ( except for TypeError: person is undefined ) the problem is with the search function itself because it doesn't print anything with right argument.

Comment: This is wrong. Unless `contacts` is redeclared in the function scope, calling `contacts` in the function will get you the global variable

Comment: @YiJiang Thank you. I didn't know it was only if you declared the same var in the function.

Comment: @WouterJ You might want to read up about scopes in JavaScript: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes

Answer (score 0):

```
var personList = [
    { 'FirstName' : "John", 'LastName': "Doe"},
    { 'FirstName' : "Jane", 'LastName': "Deen"}
]


function PersonSearchService() {  
  this.Print = function(person) {
     console.log(person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName);
  }  
  this.Search = function(lastName) {
      for(var p in personList) {         
         if(personList[p].LastName === lastName) {             
             this.Print (personList[p]);
         }
      }
  }
}

var p = new PersonSearchService();
p.Search ("Doe");
```

You can try this way